# Vue 2 favicon firefox

Tags: vue.js, firefox, nuxt.js, favicon, browsers

Продолжаю биться с фавиконками. Мне нужна одна базовая. Если доступна на сервере, то её, если нет - базовая. Я это прописываю в накст конфиге

После сборки в папку dist мб помещена 3 иконка. Тк на моменте сборки её может не быть, прописываю путь в компоненте страницы.

Дб так:
если положили в дист что-то, то её ставим. Если ничего не положили, то сначала идём на сервер и берем серверную. Если и она не находится/недоступна, тогда уже базовую из папки, которая есть всегда.

В хроме/эдже вроде всё работает, как надо. А вот фаерфокс мозги делает. Если хоть один из ресурсов недоступен, просто отказывается хоть что-то ставить.
Как побороть? Как вообще лучше эти иконки добавлять?